# How to generate two xml files?

Tags: jasper-reports

What is up everybody?
In a Front End application I have a tab called "Reports".
One of the fields on this tab that I need to fill in is called "Product". Among 3 products I choose 1 and click on a "Generate Report" button.
This Button calls a method in the JAVA backend, called getListProdutos, which is inside a class called ProdutoDao.
These 3 products were recently created in the Product table in the database, with IDs 200, 201, 202.
When I click to download the chosen product, of course, it will download the information in an Excel file for the chosen product (200, 201 or 202).
I would like to know if it is possible using the query of this same method (getListProdutos) to download another Excel file, but with information about the same type of product, but with different IDs (100, 101 and 102)?

I duplicated the getListProduct method and passed the old product information.

Answer (score -1):

You should add a column with name "type" and when you select items with IDs 200, 201, 202 use the "type" of them to find related items.
I hope i understand your requirement well.

Comment: Thank you very much Iman Soltani.
I'll try do this option.

Comment: If it works for you or not, comment the result.